# Modern Classification of Introspective Psychopharmacological Drug Profiles?

Tags: neuroscience, pharmacology, psychology, psychoneuropharmacology

In the effort to better relate neuronal mechanisms to states of mind, it makes sense to have - in addition to pharmacological classifications of drugs and imaging/physiology classifications of their effects - classifications of the states of mind they evoke, according to introspective reports.

I have been unable to find such a data-driven classification in the literature (I would imagine a cluster analysis of reported terms, or a factor analysis of ratings on statements could be appropriate). Instead, "subjective effects" classification seems to be restricted to single-substance profiling, and elsewise is remarkably top-down - based on ad hoc models by the same authoritative people or entities which commonly make psychoactive substances available to consumers (introducing confirmation bais). I'm wondering if there's anything else out there?

Comment: A couple things...1) This might be better suited for psychology.SE, and 2) I think you might be having too high a view of the state of neuroscience. Very few psychoactive drugs are truly understood from an imaging/physiological/pharmacological nature; they are pretty much all classified by their effects. Consider anesthetics, for example. Drugs like propofol, isoflurane, etomidate, etc have diverse chemical and pharmacological profiles - we group them because they cause anesthesia.

Comment: What you suggest could be done but I ponder on its usefulness. Say we relate mood swings with 60% serotonin and 40% GABA. Does that mean that if we have mood swings we adjust our serotonin and GABA levels accordingly? I think modern neuroscience is aiming at a more in-depth understanding. I suggest instead that we'd need to know which circuits it up- or down-regulates.